# Hibernate is not returning fields with null values in the resultset

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have this repository call:

```
@Query("select t1.field1, t2.field2, t3.field3 from t1 join t1.t2 join t1.t3 where t1.id = :idUser")
List<Object> getUserProfile(@Param("idUser") String idUser);
```

I try to get the values from resultset as follow:

```
        if (obj != null) {
        for(Object oArray : obj) {
            Object[] o= (Object[]) oArray;
..
        }
```

> If 
>   t2.field2

is null, the array "o" has the following indexes : o[0], o[2], so once I iterate over index 1, there is an exception, because the index 1 doesn't exist. As you can see, the indexes **are not** consecutive [0,1,2].

The work around is to validate the null value in the query. But I guess this is not good for a developer, or not expected from Hibernate at least.

Roo 1.2.4; Java 1.7; Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.2.2

However this could be a huge concern if this is a bug in Hibernate.. Could someone help me with this doubt?

Thanks!  / JR.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to define a ViewDTO containing a constructor to take all three select parameters

- t1.field1
- t2.field2
- t3.field3

Add also getters to all these fields.

and change the query to:

```
select NEW mypackage.ViewDTO(t1.field1, t2.field2, t3.field3) from ...
```

So you will get a list of ViewDTO instead of an array. This way you can handle nulls better.

For more details follow [this article](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/projection.php)

Comment: Thank you Vlad, eruiz, your support helped me a lot. I tried to click on arrow up for good answer but I got: Vote Up requires 15 reputation message.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to get the values from ResultSet, Spring Data do it for you.

Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.query-methods.at-query